# Вывод данных через OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#

Всем привет! Допустим я хочу вывести данные после коннектора OleDbConnectionStringBuilder. Где написать sql запрос и выполнить его значения?

```
OleDbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0";
builder.DataSource = @"C:\Sample.mdb";
string savedConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
connection = new OleDbConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
string command = 'Select * from Student;';
OleDbDataAdapter adapter new OleDbDataAdapter(command, connection);
adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
// Вот методы добавления записи
adapter.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(
    "INSERT INTO Student (StudentID, StudentName) " +
    "VALUES (?, ?)");
//Методы изменения записи
adapter.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(
    "UPDATE Student SET StudentID = ?, StudentName = ? " +
    "WHERE StudentID = ?");
// Методы удаления записей
adapter.DeleteCommand = new OleDbCommand(
    "DELETE FROM Student WHERE StudentID = ?");
```

Какие есть методы для SELECT, чтобы вывести данные из commander в цикле правильно? В шарпе новичок, потому сомневаюсь.